# How to list Samba 4 shares using server's IP and Kerberos authentication?

Tags: samba, kerberos, file-server, share

I am successfully able to list the Samba 4.0.3 shares by using

`smbclient -L myhostname -k` command.

However I am unable to do the same by using

`smbclient -L 192.168.1.2 -k`

and I get the `session setup failed: NT_STATUS_LOGON_FAILURE` error.

However it does work when I try to do the same by using the IP **and** a username like this:

`smbclient -L 192.168.1.2 -U administrator`.

Is it possible to perform this task using the IP **and** Kerberos authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I got almost instant answer from Andrew Bartlett from the Samba Developer Team. It is simple and straightforward:

> No.  Kerberos requires the server's name to obtain the correct ticket.
>
> Andrew Bartlett

If anyone has more detailed explanation exactly why is it so, please let me know.